# ASP.Net: Cross-Browser Action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, server-side

**Background:** I have an ASP.Net C# application for giving and grading Computer Science exams. Students take an exam while the instructor monitors their progress in his/her own browser. The instructor's page show a table of all students still taking the exam and any possible security issues detected in JavaScript at their browser. Security violations and completing the exam cause a post to the exam page. Currently, the instructor has to click a button to see changes.

**Additional Details:** Student browsers have their own session information independent of the session information of the instructor. In order to have the server write new data to the instructor's browser, ASP.Net needs to use the session info for the instructor. I have tried storing all the headers and cookies from the instructor's page and then having the student page do a redirect using the headers and cookies. Although the redirect from the student page loads the instructor page using the stored state, the instructor page does not run in the stored session for that page so no access to the client browser.

**Bottom Line:** I want an event at one browser to cause a page refresh at another browser. The two ASP.Net pages can be coordinated in code in any way necessary.

I'm thinking that I need to simulate the refresh request from the instructor page including session information and do a redirect at the server. However, my searches failed to yield good clues. Anyone ever try this?

**Note:** this system is available free to others who might want to try it. Grading highlights language syntax and can run HTML and Java programs.

Comment: SignalR. It's just that simple.

Comment: Or at a more general level: Web Sockets or Long Polling (the two core features that SignalR is built on top of).

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

Another much cruder technique is to have a web page that auto-refreshes by adding a refresh meta tag to the page like this (where 5 is in seconds):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want bi-drectional feedback (which, from your question, is what you're after) have a look at SignalR. This will allow you to send updates to clients based on other clients (think of Facebook notifications). Basically:

1. Create a HUB that would handle your subscriptions (instructor subscribes to updates).
2. Students begin test as as events occur they also notify the HUB of a change.
3. The HUB then relays that message back out to the instructor.

The other method is to use some sort of server-side flag and use `setInterval`/`AJAX` on the instructor's page to check for new updates. However, SignalR does this all for you (and will do compatibility fallbacks where necessary automatically).